# Create an array of connections to the database

Tags: c++, postgresql, database-connection

Is there a way to create an array of connections in c++. I want to create something like this.

```
connection arr[5];

for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
  connection c("dbname=test user=postgres password=abc123 hostaddr=127.0.0.1 port=5432");
  arr[i]=c;
}
```

Can someone tell me how I can get create this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use STL container to store the objects of connection. Don't know your requirement but if you just want to store objects then use like,

```
std::Vector<connection> connections;
connections.push_back(c);
```

Also, PQconnectdb(strConnectionString) API returns a PGConn* pointer and you can check the pointer for success e.g. PQstatus(m_pPostgresConnection) == CONNECTION_OK